# How convert string array to float array in c++ cli?

Tags: c++-cli

I have an `String` array in VS c++/cli and want to convert it to `float`. Would you please  help me how can I do so?

I tried to do it using a loop, but I am wondering a shortest way and effective way to do so.

```
array<String^>^ Nettemprature = getDataString("Temp.csv", 11);
float Nettemp[50];
int n=0;
ifstream myfile ("Temp.csv");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
  while ( myfile.good() )
  {
    x=x+1;
    getline(myfile,Nettemprature[n]);
    Nettemp[n] = (float)(Convert::ToDouble(Nettemprature[n]));
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems have you had getting it to work?

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Can you show us your code?

Comment: @DavidYaw Please see the edited version.

Comment: Does `getline` even work with a `String^`? I would suggest that you either use Standard C++ for everything or use C++/CLI & .Net for everything and only "mix" when interfacing with existing code you need to use.

Comment: @Royeh And is that code working for you? Are you getting a compile error? Does it compile, but the runtime behavior isn't what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were attempting to read a .csv file (of ALL floats) into an array in C++/CLI, I would do something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Linq;

float StringToFloat(String^ str)
{
    return float::Parse(str);
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Func<String^, float>^ stringToFloat = gcnew Func<String^, float>(StringToFloat);

    array<wchar_t,1>^ arr_chrSeps = { '\t', ',', '\n', '\r', ' ' };

    array<float, 1>^ arr_fltData =
        Enumerable::ToArray(
        Enumerable::Select<String^, float>(
        File::ReadAllText("c:/science/managed/ReadCsvToFloatArray/Floats.csv")
        ->Split(arr_chrSeps, StringSplitOptions::RemoveEmptyEntries), stringToFloat));

    Debug::WriteLine("There are {0} total floats in the list.",
        Enumerable::Count<float>(arr_fltData));

    Debug::WriteLine("There are {0} distinct floats in the list.",
        Enumerable::Count<float>(
        Enumerable::Distinct<float>(arr_fltData)));

   return 0;
}
```